# AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer error code

Tags: iphone, audio-streaming

I am using Audio Queue services in my application which plays audio streamed over network.
sometimes I get an error when I make a call to AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer and the function returns OSStatus code -50. Audio Queue services reference does not specify's this error code.
I am using IPhone OS 2.0 and iphone SDK 3.0 
Can anyone tell me what is meaning of this code -50?

Answer (score 2):

It's an Invalid parameter Error.

Comment: To be precise, it's called paramErr, declared in MacErrors.h.

Answer (score 0):

Is your audio queue actually running? Because if it's not - if something stopped it - then -50 is what I'd expect.